# Firefox Addon SDK: Babel support

Tags: javascript, firefox, reactjs, firefox-addon-sdk, babeljs

I'm trying to use React as part of a firefox addon I'm working on. React works fine as long as I don't use jsx. Babel isn't working - because I can't specify the type of the script I add.

I'm doing:

```
tabs.open({                                                   
    url: 'index.html',
    onReady: function( tab ){
        var worker = tab.attach({
            contentScriptFile: [
                './jquery-2.1.4.min.js',
                '../node_modules/react/dist/react.js',
                '../node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js',
                '../node_modules/babel-preset-react/index.js',
                './js/main.js', // the file i need to specify as type: text/babel
            ],
        });
   }
);
```

Ideally I'd be able to set a type property on the `'./js/main.js'` script, but the docs don't appear to have anything.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to load react, jquery, babel and your jsx directly in your html, as you usually do. The javascripts files that you'll have to load using the `contentScriptFile` param are those one that you need to load the logic to communicate with the addon main js file.

An example for a valid html will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="react-with-addons.js"></script>
    <script src="react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello!</h1>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <p>Hello, world!</p>,
        document.getElementById('example')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you tell me what you need to do in that html/content script I can give you an example of how you can do to communicate it with the main script.

Comment: Initially, that's what I tried. I was having difficulties with it - probably because I was having general communication issues with the add-on scripts. I'll take another look at it later and see if I can re-factor it.